# Canon MF Network Scan Utility - autohide/"silent mode"

Tags: networking, document-scanning

I've got this AIO printer - MF4570dn. Everything is working.. fine.

What I want is some version of *"silent"* network scan - where you just put docs in scanner and press: `Scanner -> Computer Scan -> Ok.` And scan utility puts scanned document on network (smb) drive.

Closest I've got is all that above + Network scan utility that automatically opens and closes on computer that it's installed on.

I would like to hide it or mask it - so that it wouldn't disturb user on that workstation.

I have tried several window hiding applications "TryIt!" and "Auto Window manager"  - won't help because `Canon MF toolbox` opens another *"internal"* window that those utilities won't see and for that matter can't hide.

What direction should I look? (It's winxp sp3)
(I wouldn't like to go as far as hacking terminal services or installing virtualbox or something that crazy.)

Comment: Surprisingly, I have the same problem in my office and am looking forward to automate the process.

Comment: Same for us with the Canon MF Scan Utility (2.3.0.0). I would suggest a way of extracting contents and finding a way to avoid the bootstrap installer (i.e. script a silent install after deducing what the payload actually is).
OR
Contact Canon and find out why they are causing problems for enterprise customers.